# Не загружаются картинки при открытии экзешника

Tags: python

Всем привет, я написал простенькую игру на Python, используя модуль games из пакета livewires, игра работает, все как надо... Но я хочу эту игру скомпилировать в **.exe**, компиляция проходит, всё хорошо, но при запуске экзешника, у меня не находит картинки в формате **.bmp**, хотя они находятся, в одной директории где и сам код. Я пробовал разные способы компиляции, пробовал по обычному, без ни каких флагов, "*pyinstaller pizza_panic.py*", потом пробовал с разными флагами: `"-F"` `"-D"` `"-w"`. Но без успешно.
Вот сама ошибка:
`Could not load image "pan.bmp" Couldn't open pan.bmp`

```
from livewires import games, color
import random

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)


class Pan(games.Sprite):
  
    image = games.load_image("pan.bmp")
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(Pan, self).__init__(image = Pan.image,
                                  x = games.mouse.x,
                                  bottom = games.screen.height)
        
        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color = color.black,
                                top = 5, right = games.screen.width - 10)
        games.screen.add(self.score)
```

Comment: Python-код не компилируется.

Comment: Так я это и так понял...

Answer (score 0):

попробуй указать полный путь к картинке.
.exe  исполняется программой, лежащей в системе, а не в директории с проектом.
к примеру вот так:

```
from livewires import games, color
import random

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)


class Pan(games.Sprite):
  
    image = games.load_image("C:/myprojects/propan/pan.bmp")
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(Pan, self).__init__(image = Pan.image,
                                  x = games.mouse.x,
                                  bottom = games.screen.height)
        
        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color = color.black,
                                top = 5, right = games.screen.width - 10)
        games.screen.add(self.score)
```

PS: хаххаха я только сейчас увидел что вопрос задан 2 года назад